# How to filter in collection-repeat by two or more properties for a single input text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using AngularJS 1.4.3 (for Ionic Framework 1).

I only have one `input[type='text']` field above the `<ion-list>`. I'm trying to filter this `<ion-list>` that's using `collection-repeat` directive.

Below is what the `input[type='text']` looks like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.value" />
```

My `collection-repeat` basically looks as follows:

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="thing in Things | filter: { title : search.value, aliases : search.value }">
    <p>{{thing.title}}</p>
    <p>{{thing.aliases}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

The `$scope.Things` is an array of JSON objects:

```
$scope.Things = [{
   title: "A Title 1",
   aliases: "thing1, stuff, something, string"
}, {
   title: "Title 2",
   aliases: "things 2, stuffs, commas, string"
}];
```

The `title` property is just a `string`. The property `aliases` is a string that has each word/phrase separated by a comma.

I can filter through the properties just individually. In other words, it's either I filter just by `title` or just by `aliases`. **But I don't know how to filter by both `title` and `aliases` properties in one `input[type=text]` which has the one `ng-model="search.value"`.**

Comment: I did not understand completely. What is not working with the filter you have already?

Comment: if you want an `OR` filter will need to create your own custom filter or just use `filter: search.value`. Not really clear what criteria you are wanting

Comment: if  you can make a plunker then it will help us to help you.